# getIntent().getExtra() is returing null value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, code-first

I am trying to build an android app. This is my first time working on an android app. I am facing some issues with my program in the android studio. I am trying to extract the username from the user input and send that data to the second activity. However, I am getting null in there.

[image: SecondActivity.java]

[image: MainActivity.jva Part1]

[image: Part 2 MainActivity.java]

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Could you share your code as code formatted text please?

Comment: I think the "algorithm" tag is misplaced here.

Answer (score 0):

In Main Activity your Key name is 'passdata1' , In receiving activity you are looking for 'KEY'. in second activity change it to 'passdata1'

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
nam=intentextras.getString("passdata1")
```

insted of

```
nam=intentextras.getString("Key")
```

**Explanation :**
When you send data from activity to an other activity with intent.
You should remember to use same key to get the value in other activity.

You can check this link to understand more about that:
[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 nam=intentextras.getString("KEY");
```

With this

```
nam=intentextras.getString("passdata1");
```